# python add columns to csv(at the side of csv)?

Tags: python, csv

i have a large csv file and can not load in memory at a time,i also want to add some columns  at the side of csv,so i want to add one column once a time because that does not cost many memory,i use python and pandas,so what can i do for that.
here's my code.

```
def toCsv(filepath,lists):

    i = 0
    with open(filepath,'r+') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        writer = csv.writer(f) 
        for row in reader:
           print lists
           row.append(lists[i])
           writer.writerows(row)
           i = i+1
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to modify/append to the file as you read it - that won't work. Start by creating a new file to write to, and write each row to it. That should work.

Comment: Does it have ways that can allow to read and to append at one file?

Comment: As you presumably want to replace the lines you are updating, I doubt that's possible/easy. Strongly suggest you get it working creating a new file, that's easier to test/retest so you can confirm your basic code to add columns is working. Once you have that working then if you need to that's the time to try exploring updating the file in-place, but TBH it's probably a lot simpler to do it indirectly by creating the new file, then in the script once finished delete the old file and rename new file to original filename.